# Ghostscript merge pdf font error: How to define fallback font

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

How do you give tell ghostscript to use a "fallback" font if a font can't be found?

When executing this Ghostscript command:

gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/output.pdf /input_pdf_with_missing_font.pdf

I am receiving this error:

Error: /undefined in findresource Operand stack: --dict:9/18(L)-- C2_0 1 --dict:6/6(L)-- --dict:6/6(L)-- ArialUnicodeMS --dict:11/12(ro)(G)-- --nostringval-- CIDFontObject --dict:8/8(L)-- --dict:8/8(L)-- Adobe-Identity Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 1 3 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- %loop_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %loop_continue Dictionary stack: --dict:1149/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:26/40(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: 2 GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: I have installed version 8.70

Comment: CentOS release 6.8

Answer (score 0):

You need a newer version of Ghostscript (it would help with these sorts of questions if you would state the version in use).

You appear to be using version 8.70 which is now more than 7 years old, the current version is 9.20. The current version ships with a default CIDFont (your PDF file fails to embed a CIDFont, not a Font).

You will have to check the documentation supplied with Ghostscript 8.70 to see how to define substitute resources (see the Ghostscript installation folder and then the 'doc' subfolder), I don't recall if the current method works with such an archaic version. However the current version documentation on CIDFont substitution can also be found [here](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.20/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution)

Comment: The version of Ghostscript for Centos 6.8 for yum/rpm is 8.70

Comment: Yeah well, that's what you get for using CentOS I guess, old applications. I suppose we should be grateful its from this millenium. You can download and build Ghostscript yourself, or yell at the CentOS people to upgrade their package. Or try and figure out how to do CIDFont substiutution with the old version of Ghostscript using the old documentation, and lacking the substitute CIDFont and relevant support files. Personally I'd upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I took @KenS's advice and installed Ghostscript to 9.20 (I wanted to keep the old version in place for other legacy projects)

Here are the steps (I followed these [instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1045362/667245)):

Locate the source package of GS: https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases

In my case: https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs920/ghostscript-9.20.tar.gz

Run the following commands:

```
 cd /tmp

 wget
    https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs920/ghostscript-9.20.tar.gz

 tar xzf ghostscript-9.20.tar.gz

 cd ghostscript-9.20

./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/gs9

 make

 sudo make install
```

And to run the new version:

```
/usr/bin/gs9/bin/gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/some/target/file.pdf /some/source/file.php
```

And no more font issues!!